# cakephp 2 how to suppress or catch missing controller exception

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, newrelic

Whenever somebody tries to access a non-existant url on my cakephp app I get a missing controller exception like this:

```
MissingControllerException: Uncaught exception 'MissingControllerException' with message 'Controller class AutodiscoverController could not be found.' in /app/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php:161
```

I guess this is as it should be, but it creates a problem with New Relic. This is our monitoring application and it will always register these exceptions and notify everybody that there is a problem with the application.

Is there a way to catch the exception or suppress it so that New Relic does not register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving my problem:

I installed new relic's PHP agent: `sudo apt-get install newrelic-php5`

Then I configured an ExceptionHandler for my app. In core.php:
`Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'AppExceptionHandler::handleException');`

In bootstrap.php:
`App::uses('AppExceptionHandler', 'Lib');`

The handler is located in `app/Lib/AppExceptionHandler.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php
class AppExceptionHandler extends ErrorHandler{
    public static function handleException($error) {
        if(get_class($error) == 'MissingControllerException') {
            if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
                newrelic_ignore_transaction();
            }
        }
        parent::handleException($error);
    }
}
```

The handler filters through all exceptions and if a MissingControllerException comes it's way, it uses the New Relic PHP Agent to ignore the current transaction. After the filtering the normal handleException() method by cake's ErrorHandler is excecuted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can manage it in you App controller -> beforeFilter function

```
if($this->name == 'CakeError'){
// Perform any action in error
}
```